# Why can I not change the ArrayList from my Entity Class?

Tags: java, arraylist, entity, lwjgl

In my small game I am trying to get the collision to identify and remove a Entity and then spawn a new one. I cannot change the two array lists "removeList" and "entities" as the collision code seems like it make two separate lists. I have bug tested it to see if the entities did collide and notify the computer and that was working fine.

Here is my Targets Collision Code:

```
public void collidedWith(Entity other) {
    game = new Game();
    if (used) {
    return;
    }
    if (other instanceof PlayerEntity) {
    game.removeEntity(this);
    game.spawnTarget();//This does work as I call it earlier in the code

    used = true;
    }
}
```

Here is the Game Loop Collision Code which brings the Targets Collision Code up:

```
for (int p = 0; p < entities.size(); p++) {
        for (int s = p + 1; s < entities.size(); s++) {
        Entity me = entities.get(p);
        Entity him = entities.get(s);

        if (me.collidesWith(him)) {
        me.collidedWith(him);
        him.collidedWith(me);
        }
        }
    }
```

Here is the remove entity code:

```
public void removeEntity(Entity entity) {
    removeList.add(entity);
    entities.removeAll(removeList);
    removeList.clear();
    }
```

Just a note: I know that I can remove the entity without the need of the removeList but I would like to implement the main code into the gameLoop which is where it originally started. I moved it to the removeEntity method to bug test.

I am just starting out using Entities and LWJGL so any tips would be great.

Comment: It would be nice to know why somebody down-voted this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved because I needed to make the class constructor to link back to the game class.

```
protected TargetEntity(Game game, int x, int y) {
        super(x, y, 10, 10);
        this.game = game;
    }
```

this is instead of...

```
game = new Game();
```